# How to display Dialogue bar between the Loading Time of Activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, progressdialog

I'm using gameView in my app, the load time of gameview class takes more time(10secs) to display the screen after clicking "play" button. after lot of research found that this is due to heavy data and images in my gameview class. 
So i have used this piece of code to display some progress dialogue until the gamelayer is displayed.

```
Button btnplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resumeGameButton);
    btnplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
            Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        int waited = 0;
                        while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                            sleep(100);
                            if(_active) {
                                waited += 100;
                            }
                            System.out.println("handler code...........");
                        }
                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {

                    } finally {

                        startActivity(new Intent(Menu.this, FrozenBubble.class));
                        finish();
                        //stop();
                    }
                }
            };
            splashTread.start();
        }                               
});
```

but the problem remains the same... loading time for gamelayer is more than 10sec.. during this load time blank page is displayed. please help me to solve this.

Comment: R u running your game on emulator or on your mobile?

Comment: both emulator and device @Happy_New_Year_Everyone